# Converting BMP to Gif

Tags: java, image, gif, javax.imageio, bmp

I need help to convert a .BMP image to .gif .

I am struggling with preserving the quality of the the converted gif image. I need help here . Following is the related code. Any help is appreciated.

```
//now Convert the names to lower case and change the extension to the file as a .gif file under the images directory
//you can either use URL or File for reading image using ImageIO
bufferedSourceImg = ImageIO.read(fSource);
//getting the RGB mode color value
int color = bufferedSourceImg.getRGB(0,0);
Image image = makeColorTransparent(bufferedSourceImg,new Color(color));
//getting the transparent image
BufferedImage transparent = imageToBufferedImage(image);

//generating the name of the gif image which will be created from the bmp
int idx = destFName.lastIndexOf(".");
destFName = destFName.substring(0, idx);
destFName = destFName + ".gif";
gifFile = new File(getImagesDirectory(), destFName);
//copying the gif copy of the image
Iterator itr = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("gif");
ImageWriter gifWriter = (ImageWriter)itr.next();
ImageWriteParam iwp = gifWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
String compTypes[] = iwp.getCompressionTypes();
iwp.setCompressionType(compTypes[compTypes.length - 1]);
iwp.setCompressionQuality(0);
//ImageIO.write(transparent, "gif", gifFile);
ImageIO.write(bufferedSourceImg, "gif", gifFile);
FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(gifFile);
gifWriter.setOutput(output);
IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(transparent, null, null);
gifWriter.write(null, iioImage, iwp);
gifWriter.dispose();
```

Comment: Look into image4j. I've not worked with it though.

Comment: So what is the problem with the code that you have shown?

Comment: What form does your "struggling" take?  Does this code run without errors, and if so does it produce a GIF output?  What are the specific problems you're encountering?

Comment: Yes, a gif image with very low quality ( quality of image gets generated). No exception. The only convern is the quality of gif image. What I simply want is to add transparency to generated gif images and they should be good quality

Comment: What do you mean by "quality"?

Comment: Perhaps the source image is a format that GIF isn't capable of. Why not convert to PNG instead, and see if that's better?

Comment: A GIF image can only handle up to 256 colors. Without some clever dithering and clever palette generation technique (which I'm not sure if Java does) they will presumably end up using some default 256-color palette, only a fraction of the colors of which will be relevant to your image, and naturally it will look revolting. Why aren't you using PNG?

Comment: Not related to the quality issue, but: Why do you write the image twice? First using `ImageIO.write(bufferedSourceImg, "gif", gifFile)` then using `gifWriter.write(null, iioImage, iwp)` (which writes `transparent` to `gifFile`), effectively overwriting the first file.